# API Connections only working once

Tags: java, api

I am creating an application that makes calls to the [Hitbox API](http://developers.hitbox.tv). I am trying to get the game name (listed as category_name from a list.

Thus far, I have managed to get the game name one time during the programs running stage, however when I change where to get the game name from, the program doesn't do anything. I am at a loss as to what could cause it not to send another request to the server.

```
public void apiConnect(){
    String channel = text.getText();
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpGet request = new HttpGet("http://api.hitbox.tv/media/live/" + channel);
    HttpResponse response = null;
    try {
        response = client.execute(request);
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

    // Get the response
    BufferedReader rd = null;
    try {
        rd = new BufferedReader
          (new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
    } catch (UnsupportedOperationException | IOException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

    String line = "";
    try {
        while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
          hitbox.append(line);
        }
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } 
    try {
        FileUtils.writeStringToFile(new File("hitbox.json"), hitbox.getText());
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    String game = null;
    FileInputStream fileHitbox = null;
    try {
        fileHitbox = new FileInputStream(new File("hitbox.json"));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e2.printStackTrace();
    }

    String strHitbox = null;
    try {
        strHitbox = IOUtils.toString(fileHitbox, "UTF-8");
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(strHitbox);
    JSONArray ar = obj.getJSONArray("livestream");
    for (int i = 0; i < ar.length(); i++)
    {
        game = ar.getJSONObject(i).getString("category_name");
        nameOf.setText("Game Name: " + game);
    }
    File hb = new File("hitbox.json");
    if(hb.exists()){
        hb.delete();
    }
}
```

The above sample is the defined function, and the Get Game Name button code is below:

```
btnGetGameName.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
            apiConnect();

    }
    });
```

Could anyone suggest what is causing it to not work after the first request, and if possible suggest a solution?

EDIT: I have found the issue. The reading of the data from the API is appended to the hitbox variable. I have thus added a snippet that clears what "hitbox" variable has when the button is pressed, thus meaning the code works without issues.

Comment: So where exactly does the second call get stuck? What does "the program doesn't do anything." mean? Is your widgetSelected method called the second time? Can you step trough the apiConnect() method to see what it actually does the second time?

Comment: @PeterŠtibraný I found that the file is not exiting and stays active, by adding debug steps, and the only bit failing was the file deletion

Comment: @PeterŠtibraný I managed to get it to delete the file, but now it just regenerates the same file instead of creating a new one. I'm not sure whats going wrong.

Comment: Are you on Windows? On this line `fileHitbox = new FileInputStream(new File("hitbox.json"))` you open the file, but you never close that stream. Try closing the stream before deleting the file. Also note that you don't need to store JSON content to the file first, you can use `IOUtils.toString(response.getEntity().getContent(), "UTF-8")` directly to get a JSON string. (If that response is guaranteed to be small enough)

Comment: I managed to fix it, i was using append rather than setText @PeterŠtibraný

Comment: That's good to hear, but this code is still not closing fileinputstream properly. Make sure to fix that, or it may cause you problems in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Try to consume your response after your read it to release the resource :

```
rd = new BufferedReader
      (new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));        
response.getEntity().consumeContent();
//Or if you have EntityUtils
EntityUtils.consume(response.getEntity());
```

[source](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/HttpEntity.html#consumeContent())

Comment: I tried this and the issue is still there. Console doesn't spit out any issues, but the code doesn't seem to run a second time.

Comment: Try the edit with EntityUtils maybe ? Otherwise you will need to add debug calls.